# How to convert iptables rules to ip6tables rules?

Tags: security, iptables, firewall, ip6tables

I am running a cloud service on my Raspberry Pi 3 and want to access it also from outside. Unfortunately, my ISP does not allow me to forward ports (this is another story) therefore I sometimes also need to access it over `IPv6`. To limit the access on `IPv4` I have setup the following rules

```
# /etc/iptables/rules.v4
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Fri Mar 10 18:07:14 2017
*filter
:INPUT DROP [10:3211]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [163:16092]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Mar 10 18:07:14 2017
```

Everything works as expected. However, when I try to do the same for `IPv6`, i.e., use `ip6tables` instead of `iptables` and try to apply the same rules, I cannot access it anymore over `IPv6` anymore. Are the rules for `ip6tables` setup differently?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it seems that adding the following two rules helped.

```
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 546 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p ipv6-icmp -j ACCEPT
```

Here the complete `rules.v6`

```
# Generated by ip6tables-save v1.4.21 on Wed May 17 10:14:19 2017
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [110:14552]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 546 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p ipv6-icmp -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed May 17 10:14:19 2017
```

Comment: In `iptables-save` and friends you can prepend `-4` or `-6` to a line to make it apply only to either protocol. This allows you to formulate rules that can be applied using either `iptables-restore` _or_ `ip6tables-restore`. Or move to `nft` for a more straightforward approach ...

Comment: For those wondering, like I did, the port 546 is dhcpv6-client.